# Can I escape a multi-line snippet in the view?

Tags: java, view, escaping, playframework, multiline

I need to generate an multi-line HTML snippet, to be escaped and presented to the user.

This is the raw HTML I want the user to get:

```
<h1>Here is your HTML:</h1>
<div>
  &lt;script&gt;
    alert("Hello world");
  &lt;/script&gt;
</div>
```

Which will be rendered as :

```
Here is your HTML:

<script>
  alert("Hello world");
</script>
```

I found that writing `${'<script>alert("Hello world");</script>'}` in the view will indeed escape it, but this does't seem to work for multi-line strings inside the `${''}$` - I got the following error:

```
expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway
```

Is there currently a way to escape multi-line strings in the view? (Without passing the string from the controller or anything like that)

Answer (score 1):

A better way might be to use escape().raw():

```
    ${ "<script> alert(\"Hello world\"); </script>".escape().raw() }
```

Comment: This still does not support multi-line templates.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have missed the most obvious solution: use multiple instances of `${''}`:

```
<h1>Here is your HTML:</h1>
<div>
<pre>
${'<script>'}
  alert("Hello world");
${'</script>'}
</pre>
</div>
```